# Converting data to utf8 in a write

Tags: input-encodings, write

I need to `\write` (or to `\iow_now:Nn`) a file containing utf8-encoded text, from a LaTeX file in an encoding that is not necessarily utf8 (for context: one typical use of this is to collect metadata from various articles in a journal issue and generate a joint table of contents, and e.g. titles can potentially contain accents).

This works if the input file contains encoded accents:

```
\exp_args:NNVV \str_set_convert:Nnnn \l_foo_str \mytitle \inputencodingname { utf8 }
\exp_args:NNV \iow_now:Nn \g_tmpa_iow \l_foo_str
```

Is there any way to similarly convert TeX-style accents like `\'e` to their utf8 equivalent on write (kind of like backwards `inputenc`)?

Answer (score 2):

the text functions will flatten input to text (for places like pdf bookmarks that can only have text) so

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
 \typeout{\text_purify:n{caf\'e}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

will write

café

to the terminal and log

Comment: Nice! It is not clear from the interface3 documentation that this is what it does to accents (I did not figure that mapping `\'e` to `é` was part of expansion). On the other hand, I would really like `Le \emph{caf\'e}` to be exported as `Le \emph{café}` and as far as I understand, `\text_purify:n` would simply eat the `\emph` altogether...

Comment: Perhaps using the word 'text' in my question was not the right choice